# No such method error while using RestAssuredMockMvc

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, rest-assured

I'm using `RestAssuredMockMvc` for unit testing spring mvc controllers.
This is my code:

```
import com.xyz.api.controller.UserController;
import com.jayway.restassured.module.mockmvc.RestAssuredMockMvc;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.equalTo;

public class UserControllerRest {

    private String userName = "xyz@example.com";
    private String expectedResult = "Hello " + userName;

    @Before
    public void initialize() {
        RestAssuredMockMvc.standaloneSetup(new UserController());
    }

    @Test
    public void checkResponseAndBody() throws Exception {
        RestAssuredMockMvc.given().param("userName", userName).when().get("/users").print();
        RestAssuredMockMvc.given().param("userName", userName).when().get("/users").then().assertThat().statusCode(200).and().body(equalTo(expectedResult));
    }
}
```

The first statement in `checkResponseAndBody()` prints: `Hello xyz@example.com`
But the second line gives the following error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.jayway.restassured.internal.ValidatableResponseOptionsImpl.<init>(Ljava/lang/String;Lcom/jayway/restassured/internal/ResponseParserRegistrar;Lcom/jayway/restassured/config/RestAssuredConfig;Lcom/jayway/restassured/response/Response;Lcom/jayway/restassured/response/ExtractableResponse;)V
    at com.jayway.restassured.module.mockmvc.internal.ValidatableMockMvcResponseImpl.<init>(ValidatableMockMvcResponseImpl.java:37)
    at com.jayway.restassured.module.mockmvc.internal.MockMvcRestAssuredResponseImpl.then(MockMvcRestAssuredResponseImpl.java:36)
    at com.giddh.api.restassured.UserControllerRest.checkResponseAndBody(UserControllerRest.java:25)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:78)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:212)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:68)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
```

I've seen the examples and even tried using the same code but still the error persists. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You've probably not added all dependencies to your classpath. As indicated by the [download](https://github.com/jayway/rest-assured/wiki/Downloads) page you also need to download and put the contents of `rest-assured-2.5.0-dist.zip` in your classpath.

If you're using Maven it should be enough to just depend on the `spring-mock-mvc` module:

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>com.jayway.restassured</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-mock-mvc</artifactId>
      <version>${rest-assured.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Or gradle:

```
testCompile "com.jayway.restassured:spring-mock-mvc:${rest-assured.version}"
```

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me when using restassured with Maven (Surprisingly, Gradle did not give me this problem, it handled it well unlike Maven).

For me, it was a dependency conflict. I had Apache Phoenix as dependency in my pom.xml

```
    <groupId>org.apache.phoenix</groupId>
    <artifactId>phoenix</artifactId>
    <version>4.13.2-cdh5.11.2</version>
```

This Apache Phoenix jar depends on `httpclient version 4.0.1` jar which overrides the version which my restassured jar depends on (which is `httpclient version 4.3.5`) . Maven had excluded this later version (`4.5.3`) by default.
To solve this, I added `exclusion` for  the older version under my Apache Phoenix pom section which looked like this:

```
            <dependency>

              <groupId>org.apache.phoenix</groupId>
              <artifactId>phoenix-core</artifactId>
              <version>4.13.2-cdh5.11.2</version>

              <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                   <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
                   <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
              </exclusions>

          </dependency>
```

That way the version of `httpclient` in my `restassured` jar superceded and everything worked fine.